# Connecting to Cassandra from inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, cassandra

My Cassandra instance is running on google cloud platform and I am deploying my application which connects to cassandra in a container. The application works fine when I run it without dockerizing it. Once I deploy it in the container I am getting the below error,

```
NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed
```

I tried pinging the IP of the cassandra instance from inside the container and it is not timing out and the ping looks good.

As for the container, I am using the maven:latest image to create a container and run my application using webapp-runner inside the container.

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM maven:latest
COPY . /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN mvn clean package
EXPOSE 9042 80
CMD java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/testproject.war
```

Comment: Thats a very generic exception. Check your Cassandra node logs around the same time, you might find exceptions that might give you a better idea on why the client connection failed.

Comment: Its not an issue with cassandra. The application deployed in the container is not able to reach cassandra and is timing out, there are no logs on cassandra to check since the application is not able to reach it

Comment: Ok so check your network connection inside the container, attach to the container shell and run something like `nc -v -w2 <IP> 9042` to ensure you're able to at least reach it via TCP

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a firewall issue. Can you be sure the required ports are open?
http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/faq/index.html?highlight=port#what-ports

Comment: Since it is an outgoing connection then docker should not block any ports